# Floating point problems

Tags: python, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I'm aware that floating points aren't 100% accurate in most programming languages but I've come across an odd problem just now. I'm still learning Python so have made a simple program that calculates change given in the least possible amount of coins. However, when it gets to 0.02 it seems to fail at giving a 2p coin and instead splits it to 2 1p coins. The code snippet looks like:

```
....
elif amountLeft / 0.02 >= 1:
    changeGiven.append("2p")
    amountLeft -= 0.02
else:
    changeGiven.append("1p")
    amountLeft -= 0.01
```

I've looked at it in http://www.pythontutor.com and there's clearly `0.02` in the `amountLeft` on the final iteration of anything that would reduce down to that. When I check `print 0.02 / 0.02 >= 1` I get back `True` as expected.

What obvious thing am I missing here?

Comment: If you are willing to put some time and effort into getting a deeper understanding of what is going on here, I recommend reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well since you are aware that floating points aren't 100% accurate, it shouldn't surprise you to find out that 0.02 can't be represented exactly as a Python float.  It is in fact stored as something slightly higher that 0.02, which you can see if you print the value with very high precision:

```
>>> print '{0:.32f}'.format(0.02)
0.02000000000000000041633363423443
```

As you continually subtract 0.02 from your variable this small error builds up.  Here is an example starting from 1.0 to show what I am talking about:

```
>>> x = 1.0
>>> for i in range(49):
...     x -= 0.02
...
>>> x
0.019999999999999383
>>> x / 0.02 >= 1
False
```

To avoid this rounding error, use the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module instead of floats:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> x = Decimal('1.0')
>>> for i in range(49):
...     x -= Decimal('0.02')
...
>>> x
Decimal('0.02')
>>> x / Decimal('0.02') >= 1
True
```

Alternatively, multiply all your values by 100 so you are subtracting by the integer 2 instead of the float 0.02, this will also avoid the rounding error.

Comment: I hadn't realised that subtraction also causes the floating point problems. This clears that up I guess. Thanks.

Comment: (Decimal(1.1) - Decimal(0.7) - Decimal(1.2) + Decimal(0.8)) > 0 in python. Decimal is more accurate than float, but still incorrect

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `amountLeft / 0.02 >= 1` is mostly the same as `amountLeft >= 0.02` (assuming `amountLeft` is not negative), and a bit simpler.

Using integer arithmetic (working with pennies directly, would give you exact results, although you would have to add the `.` manually when displaying results:

```
from Decimal import decimal

amountLeft = round(amountLeft*100)

....
elif amountLeft >= 2:
    changeGiven.append("2p")
    amountLeft -= 2
else:
    changeGiven.append("1p")
    amountLeft -= 1
```

If you really need a program to handle decimals in an exact way, use the decimal module. Assuming the input is floating point:

```
# Assume amountLeft contains a floating point number (e.g. 1.99)
# 2 is the number of decimals you need, the more, the slower. Should be 
# at most 15, which is the machine precision of Python floating point.

amountLeft = round(Decimal(amountLeft),2)  

....
# Quotes are important; else, you'll preserve the same errors 
# produced by the floating point representation.
elif amountLeft >= Decimal("0.02"):
    changeGiven.append("2p")
    amountLeft -= Decimal("0.02")
else:
    changeGiven.append("1p")
    amountLeft -= Decimal("0.01")
```

Answer (score -4):

Welcome to floating point. 0.02 / 0.02 does not necessarily equal 1. My best recommendation would be to always use integer arithmetic for everything. I do scientific programming all day long and I have not found the problem yet that required floating point. Let me restate that for clarity: ANY problem that you think you can solve with floating point arithmetic can be solved more effectively with integer arithmetic. The only exception I can think of is when you need to use a library that only accepts a floating point input.

If you insist on using floating point you need to use a rounding function.

--------------------- or the decimal libary as FJ suggests.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll just multiply it out. The only bit that throws me is that if you simply do `0.02 / 0.02 >= 1` then it returns `True`. I've not got to that `0.02` in `amountLeft` through division (only subtraction) so it should be exactly `0.02` rather than some long decimal.

Comment: I think that's a bit of an overstatement.  How are you going to handle something like taking a square root, or even just dividing by 7?

Comment: Sorry, but `x / x` does equal `1.0` for any finite (nonzero) IEEE 754 floating-point number. You are free not to use them, but believing that `x / x` computes as something other than one is a terrible reason for not doing so.

Comment: square roots fall into the category of "external libraries" if you don't have an integer square root calculator like I do; FYI x/x does NOT equal 1 in floating point, it equals 0.10000000000000001, .... maybe or maybe it equals 0.999999999999999999999, its hard to tell without carefully studying your machine, the program and the position of the moon at the time the program runs.

Comment: `x/x` does not equal either `0.999999999999999999999` or `0.10000000000000001` because none of these numbers is a binary floating-point number, and also because it computes as one for any finite floating-point number `x`. Hey, again, it is fine not to use them if you don't like them. But since you never use them, you should refrain from attributing them properties that they do not have. A correct statement would be “floating-point arithmetic can be a little counter-intuitive and I would advise you to avoid them when possible. This is what I do and I do scientific programming.”

Comment: Great, now I have every FP spamming code newb on the web downvoting me because I criticised their precious IEEE754 baby.

Comment: Perhaps if you put forth a reasoned argument (not just a bald assertion) or, better, a reproducible demonstration that `x/x` produces `0.10000000000000001`, the newbs would reconsider their votes. Otherwise, I guess you will have to save up reputation for another day or two before you can buy that… Wait, what was it you were going to use that reputation for?